# Yii2 How to search records in gridview when the column field have ids

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii2

I have a `GridView` where I have records from another `table` with a `relation`. So I have `ids` in one `column` I fetch the title from that `table` & display it in the `column` based on `ids`. Now when I search for title by tying title name it is not `filtering`, but when I use `ids` it is filtering.

My Question is how I `filter` the `column` which have `ids` in it by string or title name?

**Example Code**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'  => $dataProviderAlreadyAssigned,
    'filterModel'   => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
     ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
           'attribute' => 'fk_library', //this is a foreign key i.e. id of library
           'label'     => 'Library',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'value' =>function($data) {
                return $data->fkTopic->fkSubject->fkCategory->fkCatalog->fkLibrary->library_name != null ? ucfirst($data->fkTopic->fkSubject->fkCategory->fkCatalog->fkLibrary->library_name) : "";
            }
        ],
        [
            'class'     => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{delete}',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I want to `filter` library by library name here, It is working when I `filter` by library id.

Comment: please provide minimal code snippet to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the example code.

Comment: You have to add custom `filter` for that attribute

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
 $names = Library::find()->asArray()->all();
  [
       'attribute' => 'fk_library', //this is a foreign key i.e. id of library
       'label'     => 'Library',
       'format' => 'raw',
       'value' =>function($data) {
            return $data->fkTopic->fkSubject->fkCategory->fkCatalog->fkLibrary->library_name != null ? ucfirst($data->fkTopic->fkSubject->fkCategory->fkCatalog->fkLibrary->library_name) : "";
        }
 'filter' => Arrayhelper::map($names, 'lib_id', 'library_name');  
 ],
```